How to add async script to pyproject.toml file to create CLI command?
I would like to create a CLI command using pyproject.toml based on async Python function. Lets say I have this Python function in example/main.py:
async def main():
    print("Hello world!")

and pyproject.toml file:
[project]
name = "example"
...

[project.scripts]
example = "example.main:main"

When I try to execute example CLI command I get this error:
$ example
<coroutine object main at 0x7af706afbb80>
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'main' was never awaited
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

It seems that pyproject.toml only supports synchronous function targets. Is there a way to tell pyproject.toml that the target is asynchronous and it has to be awaited without messing up with code?

Isn't it possible to call your async func with an asyncio.run, then wrap that in a sync func, then use that as the entry point?

See related How do I run python asynchronous script with poetry tool script?

@GinoMempin Yes, it is possible to quite simply convert async function to sync using asyncio.run and I would accept it as an answer to this question. However, I wanted to inquire is there a simpler way, e.g. like [project.async_scripts] section in pyproject.toml?
